# Using pjax, turbolinks,etc with react.js components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am in the process right now of rebuilding an entire application, which used to run on Angular.

I'm playing with different frameworks right now and am working with react.js.  I'm not using node, but am using .NET MVC5 with React.NET.

Overall, I like working with react, but I do not like having to do a full post-back to render pages.  One of the things that I like most about single page apps is the ability to control page transitions or prevent screen flashes.

I have not found any example that show how to inject fully rendered reactJS components into the DOM using link hijacking (a la pjax or turbolinks).  I know this is possible since Facebook only has a few pages that cause a full post-back, while most of the content is pushed into the DOM using the "big-pipe".

I'm interested in any sort of examples that demonstrate an application with multiple pages (not a single page todo example) that implements this type of behavior.  I have yet to find one.

Comment: Looks as if Instragram also uses a similar strategy.

Comment: You might want to check out https://github.com/ssorallen/turbo-react

Comment: And https://github.com/reactjs/react-magic

Comment: Author of turbo-react here. TurboReact uses react-magic to go from HTML to JSX to React components. It is a Turbolinks plugin that replaces the way Turbolinks writes to the DOM.